# PHP error_log & includes not working

Tags: php, error-log

So, my problem is as follows. This code works fine when I load the page via the web browser. But when I run the script from the command line like so: "php script.php" it bombs.

script.php is:

```
<?php
include_once('class.WebsiteScraper.php');
$ws = new WebsiteScraper();
$ws->test();
...
?>
```

class.WebsiteScraper.php is:

```
<?php
echo 'test';
class WebsiteScraper {
    public function test() {
        echo 'test2';
    }
}
?>
```

This returns the error:

> PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined
>   method WebsiteScraper::test()
>   in
>   ...
>   on line 4

Only when called via the command line does this happen.
Another thing to note, when I append an

```
error_log('hey there');
```

To script.php, it throws the error to the standard out, rather than in my error log. But when called from the web browser it puts it in the error log. Any ideas?

Comment: Is there an error @ the include file not being found?

Comment: No, that's the thing...I would expect an error b/c the "file didn't exist," if I put a dummy file name in does error out. So It's finding it, but unable to load the method on my class?

Answer (score 1):

Use the [command line option](http://php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.php) `--ini` to check if the command line is loading the same configuration file as apache:

```
php --ini
```

You could also call [`phpinfo()`](http://php.net/phpinfo).

It seems likely your file isn't being included - probably due to include paths.

Edit:

Try adding

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

Comment: That's it! I'm using MAMP and I edited my ini file for MAMP (used in conjunction with Apache). But the sys ini file is somewhere else.

Comment: Welp, hang on. I've checked both ini files and both are pathing correctly. But when calling the script from the command line "error_log" still doesn't work.

Comment: Also, the included files aren't returning errors - php is able to "open a stream", but none of the code in the files is being accounted for / executed.